# How to include more files in Blank Element in SharePoint 2013 project in visual studio?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013

I have a sharepoint 2013 blank solution project in visual studio. I made a "Empty Element" and it shows an item, which contains `Elements.xml`. What I am trying to do is add a custom xml file as a `sibling` to Elements.xml. And also, so that if I open a feature in Design mode, and see the list of `items in the solution`, then expand the element object I created. I expect to see both `Elements.xml` and my custom xml file. But the problem is that I only see the Elements.xml. Somehow my custom file is not being included there.

To create the custom xml file, I just right clicked the element object, and clicked Add from existing file, and then I added the xml file. But its not being recognized by the Design mode.

I tried a hack, where I created another empty element, and renamed its elements.xml and put it as a sibling to my first elements.xml, and that was recognized, but I don't think this is the right way to do it.

I want to add a file here where the red arrow is.

[image]

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: The "empty element" is meant to represent some artifact group: a module, field definitions, etc. The element.xml is the main part in the group, as it defines the group contents. Your custom xml file should be listed in it somehow, but HOW it should be listed depends on what you need to do. Where should that custom file end up in your SharePoint site? A library?

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to change its deployment type in properties from no deployment to element.